# Setting new Entity Object for Update in C#, overiting the old object

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql

I am pretty new to Linq and C# and have a question that has been causing me alot of problems.

I have some XML that I map to a Linq Entity. What I am trying to do is load the original record in the database and then update that record based on the XML Entity Object.

Example

```
Car objXml = getXml();

var dc = new carsdatacontext();

var curr = dc.car.firstordefault(c => c.id == "22");

objXml.id = 22;

dc.car = objXml;

dc.submitchanges();
```

Basically, I just want to overwrite all the data in my DB with the data from my XML Object, but I keep getting errors like the one below.

How can I update the DB with the new Object, do I have to copy it over instead of setting it?

An entity can only be attached as modified without original state if it declares a version member or does not have an update check policy.

Comment: dc.car is a whole table not, and you only want to update a single record?

Comment: dc.car is a table, and yes I just want to update a single record. objXml.id is just the primary key that I assign to the XML object from the original DB Object ID.

Both ObjXml and dc.carr are the same entity just with different data. dc.car is from the db, objXml is what I want to overwrite dc.car with and then update the record.

So -- dc.car = objXML (Are same types just with different data)

Comment: if you wanna change the curr record then you should try assign it like curr = objXml; but i think that will not work you will have to update the curr records data one by one from ObjXml.

Comment: Not sure how you mean? Attach it to a new context?

Comment: no curr is you car object from the database right, and objXml is your object from xml, now you want your database object to have the same data as the objXml object to achieve this i think you will have to set every single property like for example curr.Manufacturer = objXml.Manufacturer and if you are ready just call the dc.submitchanges();

Comment: SHould I use reflection?

Comment: why would you need reflection?

Answer (score 0):

I hope this example will help you understand how to update a row.

[MSDN example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb399339.aspx)

Comment: I know how to update a row. That is not the problem. The problem is replacing the original object with a new object with same primary key and running an update. That is all I want to do. Seems like it should be straight forward. Pecking out 30 fields is not something I want to do and this is just one of many contexts I will have to make. So finding a solution (to what seems should be an easy fix) it imperitive.

Comment: Then maybe you could try to detach the old one and attach the new one and then submit changes. I personally have never done that but seems that could be a solution for you.